# I've found a lot of duplicates of the same question. How can I merge them all?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, duplicate-questions

I've noticed that the question of [whether or not it's possible to switch the browser to fullscreen using JavaScript](https://www.google.com/#q=javascript+change+to+fullscreen+site:stackoverflow.com&psj=1&ei=O46VUZuJCq2l4AO9l4G4DA&start=30&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=1e8c6f387dd6af43&biw=1366&bih=639) has appeared on Stack Overflow many, many times, and I'm not sure how all of these duplicates should be merged, or in what order. Does Stack Overflow have any kind of process for merging groups of duplicate questions?

**So far, I've found 10 questions that ask whether it's possible to change to fullscreen mode programmatically, and I'm trying to find an easy way to merge them all:**

[onclick go full screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900701/onclick-go-full-screen)

[Could a website force the browser to go into fullscreen mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228377/could-a-website-force-the-browser-to-go-into-fullscreen-mode)

[Switching the browser to full screen from Javascript, possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782315/switching-the-browser-to-full-screen-from-javascript-possible)

[Switch window between normal and full-screen mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436376/javascript-switch-window-between-normal-and-full-screen-mode)

[How to make the window full screen with Javascript (stretching all over the screen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen)

[How to switch the web browser to fullscreen mode with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155867/how-to-switch-the-web-browser-to-fullscreen-mode-with-javascript)

[Javascript for full screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182796/javascript-for-full-screen)

[Is possible automatic fullscreen with html5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11567993/is-possible-automatic-fullscreen-with-html5)

[Automatic full size browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9771525/automatic-full-size-browser)

[fullscreen through javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131888/fullscreen-through-javascript)

**Additionally, I've found 4 questions that ask whether it's possible to check whether a web browser is in fullscreen mode:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541697/detect-full-screen-mode

[JavaScript - detecting if user is browsing the internet using Fullscreen mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977180/javascript-detecting-if-user-is-browsing-the-internet-using-fullscreen-mode)

[How to detect if user has enabled full screen in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617963/how-to-detect-if-user-has-enabled-full-screen-in-browser)

[Detecting if a browser is in full screen mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047319/detecting-if-a-browser-is-in-full-screen-mode)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a merge process for questions, but that feature is limited to diamond moderators only.  This feature will basically merge all if the answers under a single canonical question.

In general, if you have 3K rep, you can vote to close each of the other questions as a duplicate of the best question (doesn't need to be the oldest though).  It will take 4 more users (or a diamond moderator to agree to actually close the question.

Since you do not yet have 3K rep, flagging is your best option.  It will be similar to voting to close, except your flag will send the question to the [Close Vote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/close/) review queue for 3K users to act on and vote to close (assuming you flag it as off-topic - other flag types will go to other review queues for moderators, both 10K users and diamond moderators)

But in this case, since there are so many questions, this Meta post might be the best option to do it in bulk, as a diamond moderator will see it and hopefully act on it if they feel they are legitimate duplicates.

This question got enough attention to at least one of the posts as [Switching the browser to full screen from Javascript, possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782315/switching-the-browser-to-full-screen-from-javascript-possible) is now closed as a duplicate.

Comment: _"flag will send the question to a queue for 10K users "_ -- per my observations, flag tather sends question to regular [CV queue](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close), available for 3Kers. In this queue, I sometimes see questions without close votes which makes me feel these are from flaggers

Comment: @gnat thanks, I wasn't wasn't aware of it, but it makes sense since I see questions in the MSO review queue without existing close votes.  I will update.

Comment: Could you point to an example of a Canonical question, to see how it groups the others? Thanks

Comment: @sancho.s depends on what you mean.  If you are referencing my first sentence with the merge process - there is no grouping.  The mod simply merges the questions so there is a single question, and all of the answers from all of the questions are then made as an answer to the single merged question.   There is nothing special about a merged question and it looks just like any other question.  the edit history will show the merge.  I don't know of one off the top of my head, and you can't search for them so i can't provide a link.  Maybe someone who sees this in the future will provide a link.

Comment: I was referring to your first sentence, precisely. So I would not be able to see an example, and I guess Merged questions are related to my proposal, but would not produce the same result.

Comment: @sancho.s did some searching through meta questions about merging ([meta-tag:merged-questions]) and found https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/24623/revisions.  You see the revision history shows it was merged, and that is the only sign that it was merged