# What is the largest number of questions being duplicates of one another ("Groups of duplicates")?

Tags: support, search, duplicate-questions

Many people have found questions asked once and again. The reasons for the OP to post a dupe might be varied (lazy at searching, unlucky at searching, feeling that the question being posted is actually different, etc.)

Some have put together a "Groups of duplicates" as an example, for instance, [(1) Group duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211366/group-duplicate-or-multiplicate-questions-for-convenience), [(2) Merge duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180574/ive-found-a-lot-of-duplicates-of-the-same-question-how-can-i-merge-them-all) and [(3) Text-shadow in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Text-shadow%20in%20IE&submit=search).

**What is the largest number of questions being duplicates of one another?**

For instance, for item (2) above, it is N=10.

In what follows, I provide other examples that I found... they may be useful.

---

[How to pass all arguments passed to my bash script to a function of mine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811345/how-to-pass-all-arguments-passed-to-my-bash-script-to-a-function-of-mine)

[Propagate all arguments in a bash shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824590/propagate-all-arguments-in-a-bash-shell-script)

[How do I forward parameters to other command in bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537673/how-do-i-forward-parameters-to-other-command-in-bash-script)

Answer (score 2):

SEDE has an answer for you. I just ran it on Stack Overflow since I think that is the site with the highest count, but I didn't check.

This [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/620602/posts-with-highest-count-of-duplicates) gives you this results:

```
# dups  title
------------------------------------------------------------
  6398  What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?
  3186  How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?
  2990  What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?
  2402  How do I compare strings in Java?
  2354  PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"
  1968  PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?
  1850  mysqli_fetch_array()/mysqli_fetch_assoc()/mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource or mysqli_result, boolean given
  1822  What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?
  1439  How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP
  1365  PHP mail form doesn't complete sending e-mail
  1261  Is floating point math broken?
  1147  Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?
  1075  Event binding on dynamically created elements?
  1074  JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example
  1071  How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?
```

Comment: This is fantastic! Now, it seems that looking for duplicates can be automated. Or is this just counting the duplicates that were flagged by hand (unlikely, given N=6398)?

Comment: No, these are the linked questions. The questions are all closed and just one link per question.

Comment: I did not understand this comment... ( "linked question" == "flagged as duplicate" )?

Comment: I think I dupehammer using 2 & 3 about 4-5 times per day, and I was surprised not to see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example in your list

Comment: It is there right? @Jamiec Pre-last

Comment: @PatrickHofman my bad. didnt see it down there

Comment: @PatrickHofman - If I understood correctly, even if the posted query provides very interesting info, it does not address the OP. I did not mean to find linked questions, but duplicates.